# How to split a ConstrainedOnceSequence in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, sequence

I have an issue while I was working with a sequence.
I read a very very long csv file, so I used a sequence.
Now the sequence must be filtered to two separate sequences.
See example below, showing the problem.

The problem appears because the Sequence is a ConstrainedOnceSequence, which can just be consumed once (See errormessage below).
It is not possible to store the reading result as a list in memory.

```
try {
    val data = file
        .bufferedReader(charSet)
        .lineSequence()
        .drop(1)
        .map { line ->
            EntryWithNumber.fromString(line, SEPARATOR)
        }

// The result will not be just printed, it will be processed otherwise
    data.filter { it.number != "" }.also { println(it.toList()) }
    data.filter { it.number == "" }.also { println(it.toList()) }
}

finally {
    csvData.close()
}
```

This code leads to the error:

> "Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.IllegalStateException: This sequence can be consumed only once."

The first println will be executed, the second throws the error.
I have no idea how to solve such a problem.

Comment: Can you simply read the file twice? If two filtered sequences are not being consumed concurrently, and you can’t store them in memory, I don’t see how this could be done, not just with the existing tools, but also it’s a logically impossible set of requirements. If possible, I would consume the sequence one time, using an if/else in your `forEach` instead of using filter operations.